# How to remove complete unique value from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

How to remove complete record of same object in array please help me this, I am using below funtion but its only remove one value I want remove complete object of same object

```
var data = [{
    "QuestionOid": 1,
    "name": "hello",
    "label": "world"
}, {
   "QuestionOid": 2,
    "name": "abc",
    "label": "xyz"
}, {
   "QuestionOid": 1,
    "name": "hello",
    "label": "world"
}];

    function removeDumplicateValue(myArray) {
                    var newArray = [];

                    $.each(myArray, function (key, value) {
                        var exists = false;
                        $.each(newArray, function (k, val2) {
                            if (value.QuestionOid == val2.QuestionOid) { exists = true };
                        });
                        if (exists == false && value.QuestionOid != undefined) { newArray.push(value); }
                    });

                    return newArray;
                }
```

I want result like this

```
[{
   "QuestionOid": 2,
    "name": "abc",
    "label": "xyz"
}]
```

Comment: this is not duplicate ... they remove unique value .. i want remove complete both object.. not one

Comment: he's not "removing duplicates", he's "removing all duplicated objects leaving _only_ those occurring only once"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reduce.

```js
var data = [{"QuestionOid": 1,"name": "hello","label": "world"}, {"QuestionOid": 2,"name": "abc","label": "xyz"}, {"QuestionOid": 1,"name": "hello","label": "world"}];


let op = data.reduce((op,inp)=>{
  if(op[inp.QuestionOid]){
    op[inp.QuestionOid].count++
  } else {
    op[inp.QuestionOid] = {...inp,count:1}
  }
  return op
},{})

let final = Object.values(op).reduce((op,{count,...rest})=>{
  if(count === 1){
    op.push(rest)
  }
  return op
},[])

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).Filter the array matching `QuestionOid` value equal to 1

```js
var data = [{ "QuestionOid": 1, "name": "hello", "label": "world" }, { "QuestionOid": 2, "name": "abc", "label": "xyz" }, { "QuestionOid": 1, "name": "hello", "label": "world" }]

var res = data.filter((a, b, c) => c.map(i => i.QuestionOid).filter(i => i == a.QuestionOid).length == 1)
  
console.log(res)
```